# Ошибка: Parallel.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова

Tags: c++, mpi

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int a[5];
    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = rank;
    if (rank == 1)
        MPI_Send(&a[1], 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else {
        MPI_Recv(&a[0], 1, MPI_INT, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        std::cout << a[0];
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Помогите разобраться. Ошибка на этой строке: `std::cout << a[0];`
`Ошибка: Parallel.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова.`

Comment: Почему  MPI_Recv(&a[0], 1, MPI_INT, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status) а не  MPI_Recv(&a[0], 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status)? Не хорошо знаком с этим интерфейсом, но кажется  Вы блокируете процесс сами.

Comment: Если делать так то программа просто подвисает и ничего не происиходит